# Flutter: How to integrate Firebase cloud messaging with flutter local notifications for a closed app?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a chat application that displays chat style notification only possible through flutter local notifications. I am able to generate the notifications when the app is in the foreground and background but as soon as I remove the app from the recent list the notifications stop. I have tried almost every proposed solution on github and stackoverflow and I can't seem to make that possible. Also is there a way to debug the app when it is closed since the debug gets detached as soon as the app closes.

Application.kt

```
package com.example.wesolve

import com.example.wesolve.FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant
import com.example.wesolve.FlutterLocalNotificationPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {    
override fun onCreate() {   
     super.onCreate()       
     FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)    
    }   
    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {  
        if (registry != null) {    
            FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)            
            FlutterLocalNotificationPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)     
       }   
    }
}
```

FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt

```
package com.example.wesolve


import android.util.Log
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin

class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant {    
    companion object {        
        fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
            Log.d("FirebaseCloudMessaging", "registerWith");
            if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {                
                Log.d("Already Registered","");                
                return
            }
            try {
                FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
            } catch (e: Exception) {                
                Log.d("FirebaseCloudMessaging", e.toString());            
            }            
            Log.d("Plugin Registered","");        
        }        
    private fun alreadyRegisteredWith(registry: PluginRegistry): Boolean {     
        val key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant::class.java.canonicalName    
        if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {              
            return true            
        }          
        registry.registrarFor(key)          
        return false        
    }   
}}
```

FlutterLocalNotificationPluginRegistrant.kt

```
package com.example.wesolve

import android.util.Log
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry

class FlutterLocalNotificationPluginRegistrant {    
    companion object {        
        fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {            
            if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {                
                Log.d("Local Plugin", "Already Registered");               
                return            
            }            
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin")) 
        Log.d("Local Plugin", "Registered");        
    }        
    private fun alreadyRegisteredWith(registry: PluginRegistry): Boolean {            
        val key = FlutterLocalNotificationPluginRegistrant::class.java.canonicalName            
            if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {                
                return true            
            }            
        registry.registrarFor(key)            
        return false        
    }    
}}
```

*PS. I have also tried to make an exemption for auto start in my smartphone.:/*